# GetAddrInfo and multiple threads or GetAddrInfoExA and WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Tell me please, here is an example from MSDN of calling a function GetAddrInfoExA asynchronously using WaitForSingleObject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject

My question is: will there be a big difference in performance if you just call a synchronous function GetAddrInfo by running it in different threads, waking up threads as needed versus calling GetAddrInfoExA and WaitForSingleObject ?

Comment: It depends on too many other details of the hypothetical program that you haven't specified.

Comment: @zwol, suppose there is nothing else in the program except a request to the DNS.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but I would like to suggest using overlapped I/O instead of a thread. This makes GetAddrInfoEx asynchronous.